# Ansible uri task involving body.json for API call to update a field results in Error

Tags: api, ansible

I am trying to invoke an API call from Ansible via `uri` to update maxThreads field as outlined in here https://help.boomi.com/bundle/developer_apis/page/r-atm-Shared_Server_Information_object.html

Below is the Ansible task

```
---
- hosts: localhost 

  tasks:
     - uri:
        url: https://api.boomi.com/api/rest/v1/accountId/SharedServerInformation/id/update
        method: POST
        body: "{{ lookup('file','body.json') }}"
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: 'application/json'
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
          url_username: "userdev"
          url_password: "idontknow"
        register: result
        body.json:
          {
            "maxThreads" : 100,
            "atomId" : "3456789a-bcde-f012-3456-789abcdef012"
          }
```

Playbook exesution results in error as below

```
TASK [uri] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find 'body.json' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: body.json"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong or any suggestions for alternative approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you look at the error message? It says `could not locate file in lookup: body.json`. That seems like a big clue as to the source of your problem.

Comment: `body.json` is internally defined. Not sure but I am under the impression `body.json` can be defined this way as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "internally defined". You are asking Ansible to read the contents of a file named `body.json` and it can't find it. Does it exist? Where is it relative to your playbook?

Comment: `          {
            "maxThreads" : 100,
            "atomId" : "3456789a-bcde-f012-3456-789abcdef012"
          }`

It is inside the playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know from which documentation you got the above `uri` example and syntax but probably not from the [official one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html).

What I understand is that you want to pass a json payload to your POST uri endpoint. One way to do that is to read an existing file on your controller, in which case you will use the `file` lookup to get that file content.

```yaml
body: "{{ lookup('file', 'local/path/to/existing/body.json') }}"
```

Of course, that file must exist on your local machine or you will get an error. It should also contain a json representation of your data (or eventually yaml as `uri` will convert accordingly if you set the corrects parameters - see below)

An other way is to simply pass the values inline directly in the body (or from an other variable defined elsewhere)

```yaml
body: 
  a_parameter: value1
  other_parameter: value2
  some_list:
    - ab
    - cd
  a_dict:
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
```

In both cases, you need to set `body_format: json` as your correctly did. but there is no such parameter as `"body.json"` (i.e. string value of a given key parameter to `uri`).

Comment: Thank you Zeitounator. That is how I am expecting to pass the value via `body:` but ended up the way I tried which was not getting me the required results. Thanks again